# Rooted, but Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, file-transfer

I rooted my Alcatel OneTouch S'Pop using an exploit app Framaroot.apk. 
When I tried to push a file to `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` using Eclipse's File Explorer, I got this error:

```
[2015-01-06 23:00:29 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2015-01-06 23:00:29] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

Pulling the file has no problems and I edited it to remap my camera button as a power button because the power button doesn't work well.

Could this be because the exploit method wasn't a good idea or do I somehow have to change the system folder to be R/W? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remount your /system partition be mounted as a read/write partition

What you need to do is

`$ su`

`# mount -o remount,rw /system`

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Can you tell me where the console into which I need to type that code is?

Comment: @Foxcat385 Android Shell. Either use adb or get a terminal emulator on Play Store

Comment: Thanks. The terminal emulator worked, but the keyboard keys weren't remapped.

Comment: @Foxcat385 next question :)